# How am I accidentally filtering my input?

Tags: c

```
        int velikostVstupu=0;
        while(scanf("%d", vstup+velikostVstupu)!=EOF){
                velikostVstupu++;
                if(velikostVstupu>2000){
                        printf( "Nespravny vstup.\n");
                        return 0;
                }
        }
```

This code is supposed to input no more than 2000 `int` values into my array "`vstup[2000]`". But nowhere do I check if the input is `int`, yet if it isn't, it succeeds my "`if(velikostVstupu>2000)`" (that's where I check if I am not over 2000).

Why is that? What is the math behind that?

Comment: @ChristianHujer No. The return value of [`scanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE) is `>= 0`, or the *negative* value `EOF`. You are describing the value of [`errno`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), which must be determined to be applicable by first checking the stream with `ferror` when `scanf` returns `EOF`. Those macros you have listed are defined as *positive* values, and would conflict with valid conversion counts returned by `scanf` (for example, `EINTR` is commonly `4`).

Comment: Because arrays in C are indexed from 0, the standard idiom for a `for` loop over the elements of an array of 2000 entries is `for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)`.  This avoids access the non-existent array element 2000; the largest valid index is 1999.  Your test `if (velikostVstupu > 2000)` should be `if (velikostVstupu >= 2000)` to avoid accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: The line `while(scanf("%d", vstup+velikostVstupu)!=EOF){` is dubious, too.  If there's a letter or punctuation character in the input, `scanf()` will return `0`, leaving the erroneous character for another operation to try — which will be the next `scanf()` that just failed. The simplest fix is `while (scanf("%d", vstup + velikostVstupu) == 1)`, which breaks the loop on any error or EOF. An alternative is to handle a return value of 0 with code that reads past the invalid character. It's usually best to read to the end of the line: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you. Thanks to you i know what is happening. it reads only until non number leaving the rest in buffer. When the next one asks it ignores white spaceses and he instantly finds a non number taking nothing and leaving buffer the same but incementing velikostVstupu. And this goes on until velikostVstupu>2000.

Comment: If you input contains non-numbers (other than whitespace) `scanf()` will fail to ready any input and the value of your array from that point on contains undefined values.  You could fallback here but %s will read numbers so you may need `%[^0-9]`.   Alternatively read a chunk and parse the result.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` may fail to read a number and return `0`.  Unless the input buffer changes it will do so forever till you reach your count limit.  Each of arrays will be undefined after that point.  You haven't told us how what that input looks like to handle the "skip non-numbers".

You overflow the array when you read entry with `vstup == 2000` as the test is after you already read in the value (undefined behavior).  This is how I would write it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_VSTUP 2000

int main(void) {
    int vstup[MAX_VSTUP];
    size_t velikostVstupu=0;
    for(; velikostVstupu < sizeof vstup / sizeof *vstup; velikostVstupu++) {
        if(scanf("%d", vstup+velikostVstupu) != 1)
            break;
    }
    printf("Nespravny vstup %zu.\n", velikostVstupu);
}
```

and here are some example runs:

```
$ seq 1 | ./a.out
Nespravny vstup 1.
$ seq 2000 | ./a.out
Nespravny vstup 2000.
$ seq 2001 | ./a.out
Nespravny vstup 2000.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JonathanLeffler i think i know what is happening when inputing non number. it reads only until non number leaving the rest in buffer. When the next one asks it ignores white spaceses and he instantly finds a non number taking nothing and leaving buffer the same but incementing velikostVstupu. And this goes on until velikostVstupu>2000.